# matplotlib inline syntax error

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm testing a python program, which contains calling for IPython. But I got errors in the following code:
If I use

```
%matplotlib inline
```

I got a syntax error at the "%" symbol.
I found a solution to this problem using:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

I got error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and running the code via command line. How can I fix this ?

Comment: How are you running the code? Using `python` or `ipython`? I would suggest you to use `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I'm running the code in command line on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` is used to render plots inline in ipython notebooks. If you are running this as a script from command line, try with this line commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `%matplotlib` magic is used to display graphs (of `matplotlib.pyplot` objects). This needs UI to display. So cannot be display on command prompt.

According to [IPython documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html),

> If the `%matplotlib` magic is called without an argument, the output of a plotting command is displayed using the default matplotlib backend in a separate window. Alternatively, the backend can be explicitly requested using, for example:
>
> `%matplotlib gtk`
>
> A particularly interesting backend, provided by IPython, is the inline backend. This is available only for the Jupyter Notebook and the Jupyter QtConsole. It can be invoked as follows:
>
> `%matplotlib inline`

Simple solution would be to replace `%matplotlib inline` with `%matplotlib` and run it using `ipython`.

Alternatively, what you could do is download `jupyter notebook` and run that code there.

Or as @tihom said in comments, you could comment or remove that line and run the code but this wouldn't display the graphs and other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pylab mode in ipython. Simply run ipython --pylab in the terminal. That will launch ipython configured to be able to support the matplotlib GUI backend